# Keyboard is pushing UIView away

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, keyboard, uitextfield

In my iOS app I use several UIViews of which only 1 is displayed at a time. Via buttons I switch between these views.

Displaying a new:

```
self.viewPage2.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,568)
```

Hiding the view:

```
self.viewPage2.frame = CGRectMake(500,0,320,568)
```

One of the UIViews contain a UITextField. When I click on the this textfield the keyboard opens but the UIView is pushed away from the screen.

I expect it has to do with the textField, so I have included that source code. I have a delegate from

```
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldSearchValue: UITextField!

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    textFieldSearchValue.resignFirstResponder();
}

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    return true;
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textFieldSearchValue.resignFirstResponder();
    return true;
}
```

In the ViewDidLoad:

```
textFieldSearchValue.delegate = self
```

So the strange thing is that when opening the keyboard the UIView is pushed upwards and the initial screen from the ViewController is displayed, without my UIViews. Also the UITextField is pushed away from the screen!

Comment: Although it is not a solution, when I turn OFF AutoLayout everything is working ok. Naturally I want to use AutoLayout, so still looking for an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking for autolayout solution hence you should consider that frame updating like

```
self.viewPage2.frame = CGRectMake(500,0,320,568)
```

is not supported in autolayout.

You have to update constraints for the above to achieve.
eg:

```
self.myViewBottomSpaceConstraint.constant += 256;
[self.myView updateConstraints];
```

If you want to have more than 1 text field better embed them inside a scrollView or tableView. They will ease your pain.

Comment: That sounds logical. Due to the AutoLayout the Constrains mess up the positioning of the views!